# getting multiple documents along with queries on firestore android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve multiple document and view it but the problem is that it retrieves only one document.

```java
CollectionReference collectionReference = db.collection("users");

collectionReference
    .whereArrayContains("zip",zip)
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                String documentId = documentSnapshot.getId();
                String arrival = documentSnapshot.getString("arrival");
                String duration = documentSnapshot.getString("duration");
                String date = documentSnapshot.getString("date");
                Map distance = (Map)documentSnapshot.get("distance");
                ArrayList route = (ArrayList) documentSnapshot.get("route");

                String viewData = documentId + "\n" + arrival + "\n" + duration
                    + "\n" + date + "\n" + distance.toString();

                textView.setText(viewData);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve multiple documents with one request by querying documents in a collection.You can use where() to query for all of the documents that meet a certain condition, then use get() to retrieve the results:

```
db.collection("cities")
        .whereEqualTo("capital", true)
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

You can find the above example in the “[Get multiple documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#java_8)” document.

Comment: What will happen if I use querySnapshot.get().getDocuments().parallelStream().forEach